# The return type 'List<String>?' isn't a 'Future<Iterable<_>>', as required by the closure's context

Tags: flutter, google-maps

I am trying to use flutter [Typeahead]https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_typeahead package for displaying suggestion for the user. I get "The return type 'List?' isn't a 'Future<Iterable<_>>', as required by the closure's context". I followed the example in the documentation but can't make it work.

```
TypeAheadField(
    textFieldConfiguration: TextFieldConfiguration(
        autofocus: true,
        decoration: InputDecoration(
            filled: true,
            fillColor: Colors.white,
            hintText: 'Search Location',
            border: OutlineInputBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
            ),
        ),
    ),
    suggestionsCallback: (searchPattern) async {
        return await PlacesRepository.fetchPlaceSuggestions(searchPattern); /// error here
    },
),
```

fetchPlaceSuggestions():

```
  Future<List<String>?> fetchPlaceSuggestions(String searchText) async {
    // Fetch result for the search pattern
    final response =
        await _dioClient.get('{$_baseUrl}autocomplete/json?', queryParameters: {
      'input': searchText,
      'key': googleAPIKey,
    });

    // Check if response is successfull
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      return List.generate(response.data['predictions'].length, (index) {
        return response.data['predictions'][index];
      });
    }
    return null;
  }
```

Thanks. Cheers

Comment: what does Future<List<String>?> mean?  Is the list optional

Comment: @GoldenLion It is a null-aware operator. It enables the function to return a null list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, remove `async` in `return await PlacesRepository.fetchPlaceSuggestions(searchPattern);`, or what you get is a `value`, not a `Future<value>`, which is not compatible with the `suggestionsCallback` field type declaration.

Secondly, remove the question mark in `Future<List<String>?>`, the reason is the same. And then it works.

Demo code:

```dart
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Scroll'),
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        // currentIndex: _selectedScreenIndex,
        // onTap: _selectScreen,
        items: const [
          BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.home), label: 'Screen A'),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.settings), label: "Screen B")
        ],
      ),
      body: Container(
        child: TypeAheadField(
          textFieldConfiguration: TextFieldConfiguration(
              autofocus: true,
              style: DefaultTextStyle.of(context)
                  .style
                  .copyWith(fontStyle: FontStyle.italic),
              decoration: InputDecoration(border: OutlineInputBorder())),
          suggestionsCallback: (pattern) async {
            return fetchPlaceSuggestions();
          },
          itemBuilder: (context, suggestion) {
            return ListTile(
              leading: Icon(Icons.shopping_cart),
            );
          },
          onSuggestionSelected: (suggestion) {
            // Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
            //     builder: (context) => ProductPage(product: suggestion)));
            print("to page .......");
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Future<List<String>> fetchPlaceSuggestions() async {
    return Future.value(List.generate(2, (index) {
      return ['a', 'b'][index];
    }));
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Step 1: Check if two models have the same name and change the model name if needed.
Replace "OldModel" with the appropriate name of the old model and "NewModel" with the desired name for the new model.
Make sure to update other references to the model name accordingly in the code.

Step 2: Remove the null check where not required.
If you're confident that the `result` should never be null at this point in the code,
you can safely remove the null check for `result`.

I hope this will work for you